# How to parse a row?

Tags: excel, vba

**I need to write VBA code that:**

1. Reads in rows in a sheet
2. Checks if column E has the character ";#" and parses the string on that character
3. Creates a new row and copies and pastes the row contents from the parsed row to the new row (both rows will have the same contents)
4. Renames the original column to the word that comes before ;#" and renames the copied column to the word that follows ";#"

**Example with three columns:**
*Original row:* String A;#String B;#StringC (cell 1)    Complete (cell 2)   5/20/2019 (cell 3)

**What I need:**
*Updated_Original row:* String A        Complete    5/20/2019
*New row 1:* String B   Complete    5/20/2019
*New row 2:* String C   Complete    5/20/2019

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim SplitText
Dim WrdArray() As String, size As Integer
    
'iterate through all the rows in the sheet
For i = 1 To i = 2000
    
    'take one cell at a time
    cell_value = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
    size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(1).Columns(1))

    'Split cell contents
    WrdArray() = Split(cell_value, vbLf)
    For j = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
        Var = WrdArray()(0)
    Next j
        
    '  WrdArray().Resize(UBound(SplitText) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(SplitText)
    ReDim WrdArray(size)
    counter = counter + 1
        
    Var = SplitText

Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You say this "Creates a new row" but then in the next step you say "Renames the original column". Can you double check that you mean "Row" or "column" here. Adding rows while you are iterating those same rows is a little tricky.

Comment: Are the last 19ish characters always going to be " Complete" with a date?  If so, save the original string's last characters, inclusive of complete, e.g., `right(val,19)` and append that to each created row from the split.  Additionally, if that might vary, you can `InStr(val,"Complete")` and then determine how many characters to include.

Comment: @JNevill I'd like to add new rows while iterating those rows - i.e. I'm adding rows if a cell has "," or ";#" in it, and copying and pasting the same row values to the newly created ones

Comment: Your question specifies column B but your provided code is looking at column A.  Can you please clarify?  Also, is `String A, String B, StringC` all in a single cell, while `Complete` and `5/20/2019` are in their own separate cells (in the same row)?

Comment: Additionally, your provided code splits on `vbLf`, but your question and your comments state to split on `,` or `;#`.  Which one should it be?  If the latter, can a cell have both `,` and `;#` in it (e.g. `String A, String B;# StringC`)?

Comment: @tigeravatar sorry for the confusion - please see updated "What I need is" section above. I need to parse for the special characters ";#", which appear in a single column in the worksheet. `StringA;#StringB;#StringC` are in the same cell, and `Complete` and `5/20/19` are in two different cells on the same row. In this example, I want to have 3 rows: first row - `StringA` (cell 1) `Complete` (cell 2), `5/20/19` (cell 3); second row - `StringB` (cell 1) `Complete` (cell 2), `5/20/19` (cell 3); third row - `StringC` (cell 1) `Complete` (cell 2), `5/20/19` (cell 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you don't need the `Title` column of your screenshot in the particular order you show, this is a simple task for `Power Query` (aka `Get & Transform` in excel 2016+).

Merely

- `Get&Transform Data`  from `Table/Range`
- Split by delimiter (and your delimiter appears to be `;#` and not just `#`
- Split into rows

[image]

And you're done:

[image]

This is the M-Code for the PQ:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Status", type text}, {"Priority", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Name", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";#", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Name"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Name", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I chose to use a combo of `Len()` and `InStr()` to figure where "complete" was in your string to figure the content to append to each part of the split.  I made a few assumptions related to your columns/rows (see image below):

```
Option Explicit

Sub fdsa()
    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, s As Long, lr As Long, c As Long, z As String
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lr
        arr = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, ",")
        If InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "Complete") Then z = Right(Cells(i, 1).Value, Len(Cells(i, 1).Value) - InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "Complete") + 1)
        c = 2
        For s = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If s = UBound(arr) Then z = ""
            Cells(i, c).Value = arr(s) & " " & z
            c = c + 1
        Next s
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

Here's the data I used:

[image]

Comment: Postscript, i typed off the top of my head, so my variables aren't identical to yours, and i cleaned up a little

Answer (score 0):

Making a lot of assumptions based on what appears to be incomplete information here, but according to the information and examples provided, something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim vTemp As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim ixResult As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rData = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    If rData.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        aData(1, 1) = rData.Value
    Else
        aData = rData.Value
    End If

    ReDim aResults(1 To 65000, 1 To UBound(aData, 2))
    ixResult = 0

    For i = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
        For Each vTemp In Split(Replace(aData(i, 1), ";#", ","), ",")
            If Len(Trim(vTemp)) > 0 Then
                ixResult = ixResult + 1
                aResults(ixResult, 1) = Trim(vTemp)
                For j = 2 To UBound(aData, 2)
                    aResults(ixResult, j) = aData(i, j)
                Next j
            End If
        Next vTemp
    Next i

    rData.Resize(ixResult).Value = aResults

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @tigeravatar. I've added a comment above, but here's further clarification: I need to parse only in cells where special characters ";#" appear, which are always in column E in the worksheet (but not in every cell in column E). Additionally, `StringA;#StringB;#StringC` are in the same cell, and `Complete` and `5/20/19` are in two different cells on the same row. The result I want to have is the following 3 rows: first row - `StringA` (cell 1) `Complete` (cell 2), `5/20/19` (cell 3); second row - `StringB` `Complete` `5/20/19`; third row - `StringC` `Complete` (cell 2) `5/20/19` (cell 3)

Comment: Note that I have 22 columns and 1000+ rows

Comment: @gyny With what I've provided, you should be able to modify it to fit your needs.  If you don't understand the code enough to modify it, i recommend stepping through the code with `F8` to see what it's doing and googling anything you have questions on first.  This isn't really a "code for me" site, we help you overcome obstacles in your code.  What's provided here is a base that can be configured to your requirements relatively easily if you understand the code.